# Can one property value be passed as a argument to another property whose value is computed via a function ? (in Javascript ES6 with classes)

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6, properties

```
class A {
    constructor(inval){
    this.c = inval;
    }

b() {
return this.c + 1;
}

e(z) {
    return z+ Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}

d() {
    let x = {
        x1: this.b(),
        x2: this.e(this.b()),
    }
    return x;
}
}

var inst = new A(5);
var instret = inst.d();
console.log(instret);
```

Question: in method d() statement "let x" is it possible to use the x1 property as a argument to x2:this.e() call like this:

```
let x = {
        x1: this.b(),
        x2: this.e(x1),
    }
```

tried several combinations none worked. Basically is there a better way than to repeatedly type "this.b()" as parameter to this.e() when what I clearly want as parameter is x1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) or what @Adeel recommended

```js
class A {
  constructor(inval) {
    this.c = inval;
  }

  b() {
    return this.c + 1;
  }

  e(z) {
    return z + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }

  d() {
    let x = ((x1) => ({
      x1,
      x2: this.e(x1),
    }))(this.b());
    
    return x;
  }
}

var inst = new A(5);
var instret = inst.d();
console.log(instret);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the only way to build objects on the fly that have few of their properties dependent on other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Set key2 as a function and use `this` to access another key from the same object.

```js
var obj = {
  key1: 5,
  key2: function() {
    return this.key1 + 10;
  }
};

alert(obj.key2()); // 15
```

Comment: I still need to call this.e(), cannot eliminate it, so I can try:
let x = {
        x1: this.b(),
        x2: function() {
           this.e(this.x);
          } 
however this does not give the same result. The question is in this situation can x1 be used as an argument at all ?